# Confluent JDBC Connector with MSSQL only streams 100 rows

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

**I have a confluent JDBC Source connector , which I am using for MSSQL database, The issue is that it throws the below error as soon as it reads 100 rows. I am perplexed as I have not faced this issue with any other databases for the same connector.**

```
Error: WorkerSinkTask{id=Sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:196)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$HeartbeatThread.run(AbstractCoordinator.java:1535)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Time.timer(Time.java:79)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.pollNoWakeup(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:321)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$HeartbeatThread.run(AbstractCoordinator.java:1454)
[2022-12-14 14:35:43,647] INFO [Sink|task-0] Stopping task (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask:161)
```

**Solutions tried:**

*I have tried increasing the batch size as suggested in few forums, but still the same issue persists.*

Comment: Please [edit] to include the error as text

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

This would mean your batch size is too large for the Connect worker. Increasing the batch will make the issue **worse** since that means more memory is required.

Connect has a default max heap of `2G`... You can increase the worker memory using an environment variable, for example, to double the size.

```
export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xms256M -Xmx4G"
bin/connect-distributed.sh  ...
```

Otherwise, you'd need to *decrease* the batch size.

---

Also, you could try using Debezium instead, which will accurately capture DELETE and UPDATE queries, where the JDBC source will not.